# how to create a multi-page form in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

whats the best way to create a multi-page form in zend form and also we can use validate  fields?
someone could give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use subforms

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.forms.html#zend.form.forms.subforms